# MVC Action called twice

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a `MVC Action Method` which is being hit twice if the request takes time to complete. On checking chrome console network log and fiddler, the request is being sent only once from the JS.

In the diagram below, I'm facing this issue with `Approach 1`. However, it works fine if I do it with `Approach 2`.

**What’s happening with Approach 1 (failure):**

1. `JS` hits `MVC Action` with `window.location.href`.
2. Ideal scenario as per code

   - `MVC Action` (Time taking process)

     - Calls `Service Method 1`
     - Calls `Service Method 2`
     - Redirects to the confirmation/final page.
3. What actually happens

   - `MVC Action` (Time taking process)

     - Calls `Service Method 1`
     - Calls `Service Method 2`
     - **Waits for approximately 4 minutes (Unable to determine the reason)**
     - **Calls `MVC Action` again**
     - Validation fails and response is redirected to error page since the action method is being called twice with same parameters.

**What’s happening with Approach 2 (success):**

1. Split the `MVC Action` calls into two, 1 and 2
2. `JS` hits `MVC Action 1` using `Ajax`
3. `MVC Action 1`

   - Calls `Service Method 1`
   - Responds with the URL to `MVC Action 2`
   - JS receives `MVC Action 1` response and calls `MVC Action 2` using `window.location.href`
4. `MVC Action 2`

   - Calls `Service Method 2`
   - Redirects to the confirmation/final page successfully.

Even though I’ve found a probable solution with `Approach 2`, I can’t understand why `Approach 1` fails.

**The main points that bother me are:**

1. Why is the `MVC Action` being called twice even if the process takes long time to complete? Couldn’t it just have timed-out?
2. Why there is a gap of approximately 4 minutes before the second call happens?

[image: Alternate Flows]

**Edit:** I've tried it on `Chrome 45.0.2454.101 m`, `Firefox 40.0.3`, `IE (7, 8, 9, 10)` without any success.

```
ASP.NET MVC 2.0
.NET 4.0
```

*Note: I've looked at other similar problems (google/SO) but it didn't help me.*

Comment: Have you tried with different browsers?  It *could* be (no evidence provided) that the browser is getting a timeout so trying again, but not telling you in the console.  (though this does sound unlikely, just speculation).   It's unlikely the top3 browsers would work the same in this regard (so if it does it on all, this isn't the case).

Comment: Generally, if you have a long-running process, you don't want to use location.href.   Showing a page then a 'loading' gif is much better for the user.   Why not combine Approach2 call with Approach1 controller-action?  ie make an ajax call to Action which calls Service1+Service2.

Comment: This looks like a good scenario for [signalr](http://www.asp.net/signalr) - especially if your services can give additional feedback.

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks for your suggestion on a third approach. I'll definitely try out that approach as well. As for browsers, i've tried on all of them, including different OS.

Comment: Can you post your AJAX or JavaScript?